# WipeOut entire local data store in parse - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, local-datastore

This question has been asked too many times, but I did not find an answer to this yet.

I am struggling to clean my local data store on log out. what I am doing is I am pinning objects on various activities, and once user presses Logout, I call unpinALLInBackGround(); Apparently this does not cleans the localDataStore, once I log in from another user. I can still see the old entries.

what I want is a complete flush of entries in localDataStore.

In a particular activity:-

```
 query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        if(isNetworkAvailable()){
                            ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground(objects); // remove previous objects
                            ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(objects); // pin new objects
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

And On LogOut:-

ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground();

Comment: Check the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264245/objects-still-in-localstore-after-unpinallinbackgroundlist-deletecallback/29284571#29284571

Comment: tried that, it did not help.